# Create an XDocument from a list of XElements

Tags: c#, xml

I am looking for a solution to create an `XDocument` from a list of `XElements`.

```
List<XElement> result;
XDocument resultDocument = //to be created from result
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to put the list into a newly created root `XDocument result = new XDocument(new XElement("root", result));`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an `XDocument` from `XElement`s by embedding them inside a root tag, see the snippet below:

```
XDocument xmlDoc= new XDocument(            
        new XElement("Root",
            new XElement("Child1", "result1"),
            new XElement("Child2", "result2"),
            new XElement("Child3", "result3")
        )
    );
```

or if you have a `List<XElement> result` you can do the following:#

```
XDocument xmlDoc= new XDocument(            
    new XElement("Root",
        result
    )
);
```

Comment: Say I have List<XElement> result. I want this result to create xdocument

Comment: updated answer to include a List<XElement>